# How do I write a rule for Apex PMD that allows it to recognize custom objects?

Tags: apex, custom-object, pmd

I'd like to eliminate any warnings from Apex PMD that triggers alerts on custom objects for my Salesforce organization. Is there any way to add my custom objects to the linter?

For example, when I am creating an instance of a custom object I get a yellow underline that gives me a message of "InvalidType", No quick fixes available.

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? What kind of errors are you seeing?

Comment: Have you tried sobject refresh in vs code?

Comment: @user56430 unfortunately, that did not work.

Comment: @alfwhfwef probably java location isn't set correctly for apex server.

Comment: @user56430 that is the correct answer with a caveat. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in my installation of VS Code that allows data to persist in the background even though Workspace and User settings have been changed. I updated my User settings java location to overwrite the hidden info.

Comment: Can you provide the specific settings and actions you took to fix the error?